# Read XML file with XmlReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a xml file like this.

```
<response>    
    <status>ok</status>\r\n
    <number>125698</number>
    </response>
```

I want to read number if status is "ok".
so this is my code

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Response)))
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("response");
                    reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("status");
                    output.AppendLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                }
                OrderResponse = output.ToString();
                OrderResponse = OrderResponse.Replace("\r\n", "");

                if (OrderResponse == "ok")
                {
                    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Response)))
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("response");
                        reader.MoveToNextAttribute();

                        reader.ReadToFollowing("number");
                        output.AppendLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                    }

                    string orderNo = output.ToString();
                    orderNo = orderNo.Replace("\r\n", "");
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["orderNo"] = orderNo;
```

but orderNo output like "ok125698".
but I want only "125698" this.
How to read it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: why do you have `\r\n` in your XML file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not resetting `output` before your second call to `AppendLine`, causing `output` to contain (at least) two lines: "ok" and "125698". Then you set `orderNo` to this string, replacing out the `\r\n`, yielding "ok125698".

Perhaps you meant to use a different `output` variable or to clear its contents?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're appending the order number to the output variable after you have already appended the status value to it:

```
reader.ReadToFollowing("status");
output.AppendLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

reader.ReadToFollowing("number");
output.AppendLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
```

This code it much longer than it needs to be.  Please try this:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Response)))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("response");

    reader.ReadToFollowing("status");
    string status = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    if (status == "ok")
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("number");
        string orderNo = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["orderNo"] = orderNo;
    }
}
```